# Передача в конструктор класса неограниченное количество аргументов

Tags: c++

возникла проблема с тем, чтобы передать в конструктор класса заранее неизвестное количество аргументов. Я нашёл два возможных варианта решения

1. (менее надёжный) это создать указатель на последний аргумент и использовать инкременты, так как обычно аргументы лежат в памяти друг за другом, но метод, кажется мне не надёжным и появляется проблема отличить последний введённый аргумент от мусора

```
Vector(int arg, ...)
{
    int *p = &arg;
}
```

2. Использовать стандартную библиотеку stdarg.h, что будет явно адекватнее, но я столкнулся с проблемой: не могу отличить, когда заканчиваются аргументы и начинается мусор:

```
#include <stdarg.h>

class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(int arg, ...)
    {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, arg);

        std::cout << arg << std::endl;

        for (int i = 0; i = va_arg(ap, int);)
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }

        va_end(ap);
    }

};

int main()
{
    Vector a(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Вот что он выводит

```
1
2
3
12914723
12914723
16404480
14088232
2058353509
14088244
2058350259
1000937776
31
14088272
14088272
2058359868
14088272
2058350259
1000937776
31
14088300
14088300
2058359868
12914723
19291320
2001875552
14088312
2058350259
1000937776
```

Есть разные костыли, например первый аргумент использовать как количество последующих аргументов, например

```
Vector a(3, 1, 2, 3);
```

Но я бы не был программистом, если бы не ленился каждый раз думать о том, сколько там будет параметров и что случится, если я осчетаюсь. Я придумал как можно это обойти, например использовать препроцессор по типу:

```
#define a(...) a(__VA_ARGS__, NULL)
```

На данном примере работает хорошо, но я так и не догадался как написать его, чтобы он работал для всех переменных, а не только для "а".

Буду очень благодарен за подсказку или за идею как обойти этот недочет. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может проще  передавать в конструктор массив и его размер? Или тут речь об эстетике исходного кода?

Comment: @avp , этот вариант я тоже рассматривал, но во мне проснулось сильное желание сделать так, чтобы код работал, при введении только координат вектора

Comment: Передавайте в фигурных скобках список инициализации. Или просто шаблон с переменных кол-во аргументов.

Comment: Интересно, если вы используете в макросе подход с добавлением еще одного аргумента-ограничителя, то почему вы не хотите его же использовать в вызове руками? И "осчетаться" не получится. И еще — не используйте работу с `...` через указатель!!

Comment: @Harry , я хотел бы использовать этот класс в будущем в работе с математическими исчислениями, и стараюсь сделать его максимально удобным для пользователя. Понятно, что это не сложно ввести NULL в конце ручками, но тогда теряется вся магия программирования. Неужели нет способа обойти эту проблему? Спасибо вам за подсказку!

Comment: @KoVadim, Спасибо за подсказку!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) вызывает неопределенное поведение. (2) требует отдельно передавать количество элементов, и никак не защищает вас от передачи неправильного типа.

Забудьте об `<cstdarg>`, и тем более об (1).

Для контейнеров правильно писать так:

```
Vector(std::initializer_list<int> list)
{
    for (int x : list)
        stdd::cout << x << '\n';
}
```

Да, `Vector a(1, 2, 3);` работать не будет, зато `Vector a = {1, 2, 3};` будет. Так же, как у стандартных контейнеров.

Можно заставить работать синтаксис `Vector a(1, 2, 3);`, но это хуже, потому что конструктор теперь обязан быть шаблоном:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Vector
{
    template <typename ...P>
    Vector(P &&... params)
    {
        ([&]{
            std::cout << params << '\n';
            // Если вы собрались куда-то копировать/перемещать аргумент, то `std::forward<P>(params)`.
        }(), ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector a(1, 2, 3);
}
```

Тут сложность в том, чтобы запретить передавать аргументы неправильного типа. Я бы сделал так:

```
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

struct Vector
{
    template <std::convertible_to<int> ...P>
    Vector(P &&... params)
    {
        ([&]{
            int x(std::forward<P>(params));
            std::cout << x << '\n';
        }(), ...);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector a(1, 2, 3);
}
```

---

> я хотел бы использовать этот класс в будущем в работе с математическими исчислениями

Вам точно нужны вектора переменного размера? Если вектора нужны только маленькие, то обычно их шаблонируют размером, что-то типа: `template <typename T, std::size_t Size> struct Vector`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Вы сделали этот день! На счёт векторов я с Вами соглашусь

Answer (score 1):

Я бы не стал загружать себя сложностями, и передавал бы просто список аргументов. Переменное количество аргументов - это не очень стандартно. Если бы была важна скорость, то конечно можно было-бы массив с аргументом длины.

```
# include   <iostream>
# include   <list>
class Vector
{
public:
    Vector(std::list<int> const & l )
    {

        for (int i : l)
        {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }

    }

};

int main()
{
    Vector a({1, 2, 3});
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересное решение!